# radio button to get id and pass to next page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am doning one page where the packages are listed from database with a radio button it needs to save packname and echo which pack is selected

Standard Packages

```
              <?php
                echo "<table border='1'>";
                echo "<th>Select</th>";
                echo "<th>Package Name</th>";
                echo "<th>Service Type</th>";
                echo "<th>Service Name</th>";
                echo "<th>Sessions</th>";
                echo "<th>Price</th>";

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                  echo "<tr>";
                  $checked=isset($_POST["radio"]) && $_POST["radio"]==="oneway"?"checked":""; 
                  echo '<td><input type="radio" name="radio" id="oneway" value="oneway" <?php echo $checked;?></td>';
                  echo "<td>".$row['packname']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['ServiceType']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['ServiceName']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['Sessions']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['Price']."</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                 }                      


               echo "</table>";
               echo "</div>";
               mysqli_close ($db);
            ?>

            </table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you have not asked a question, so it is pretty difficult to answer. Is there anything wrong with the above code? Did you get stuck with something?

Comment: yes a radio button i have given should show only which i have selected pack name

Answer (score 0):

Change the value to `$row['id']`.

```
echo '<td><input type="radio" name="radio" id="oneway" value="$row[\'id\']" <?php echo $checked;?></td>';
```

Get the id and select the packname using the id.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']){
    $id = $_POST['radio']

    // select * from table where id = $id
}
```

Also change the id of every radio button or make it a class.